# Adding a view to a fragment from another fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a view in fragment B from fragment A, they both belong to the same activity but they are never running simultaneously

**My activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment_Main main = new Fragment_Main();
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainContainer, main)
            .commit();

  /* Fragment_Main is a fragment with two buttons
  *  to either call fragment A or fragment B and
  *  mainContainer is a FrameLayout occupying the whole screen
  */
}
```

**Fragment A:**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subjects, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentB.addMyView();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

**Fragment B:**

```
public static void addMyView(){
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 200, 0, 0);

    CustomView mView = new CustomView(mContext, "english", "a1", "10:12", "14:32");
    mLayout.addView(mView, params);

// CustomView is the custom view I want to add

}
```

**Question:**
I know that a fragment can't communicate with another fragment directly, how do I tell the activity to add a view permanently to FragmentB when the method `addMyView()` is called?

Comment: If the fragments are never running simultaneously then what's the use case for this? Because it's possible but it may be useless visually

Comment: I have a schedule with an 'add fab' when I click the fab a fragment opens, I select info for my new english class and click a button to add that info as a class into the subject. That would a possible case

Comment: Are they displayed simultenously?

Comment: No, they replace the same frameLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Persisting for one activity lifecycle

`FragmentA` should set a flag (e.g. a `boolean` attribute) on the `Activity` instance.

When `FragmentB` is instantiated, the `Activity` should pass this flag to the created instance (e.g. via `Bundle`). `FragmentB` should then decide whether or not to add the `View`.

### Persisting permanently

`FragmentA` should set a `SharedPreferences` flag.

`FragmentB` should check this flag in `onCreateView` and potentially add the `View` depending on the value.

---

**General advice:**

Solving communication between `instances` with `static` values/methods is almost always bad practice.

Comment: What is the best practice to achieve such result?

Comment: I've given two solutions above. They're equally good. Use one depending on which result you want.

Comment: I understand now, that 2nd solution would be something like creating a view with a key in fragmentA, and check in fragmentB if that key is null, if it isn't add the stored values?